# Дуга по трем точкам

Tags: java, javafx

Недавно только начал изучать java. Пробую нарисовать дугу по трем точкам. Но дуга не всегда рисуется в нужном направлении.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Arc;


public class Main extends Application {
    Point2D p1, p2, p3 ;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,500,500);
        Pane pane = new Pane();
        pane.setPrefWidth(500);
        pane.setPrefHeight(500);

        pane.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(p1 == null){
                    p1 = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }else if(p2 == null){
                    p2 = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
                }else{
                    p1 = null;
                    p2 = null;
                }
            }

        });
        pane.setOnMouseMoved(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {           
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(p1 != null && p2 != null){
                    p3 = new Point2D(event.getX(), event.getY());
                    Point2D vra = p2.subtract(p1);
                    Point2D vrb = p3.subtract(p1);
                    double ra2 = (vra.getX() * vra.getX() + vra.getY() * vra.getY()) * 0.5;
                    double rb2 = (vrb.getX() * vrb.getX() + vrb.getY() * vrb.getY()) * 0.5;                 
                    double crossp = 1 / vra.crossProduct(vrb).getZ();                   
                    Point2D center = new Point2D((ra2 * vrb.getY() - rb2 * vra.getY()) * crossp,(rb2 * vra.getX() - ra2 * vrb.getX()) * crossp).add(p1);                    
                    double radius = center.subtract(p1).magnitude();

                    double endAngle = Math.atan2(p1.subtract(center).getY(), p1.subtract(center).getX());                   
                    double startAngle  = Math.atan2(p3.subtract(center).getY(), p3.subtract(center).getX());

                    double length = startAngle < endAngle
                            ? endAngle - startAngle
                            : 2 * Math.PI + (endAngle - startAngle);

                    length = Math.toDegrees(length) - 360;
                    startAngle = Math.toDegrees(startAngle);

                    if(pane.getChildren().size() > 0){
                        pane.getChildren().remove(pane.getChildren().size() - 1);
                    }
                    Arc arc = new Arc(center.getX(), center.getY(), radius, radius, -startAngle, -length);
                    arc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                    arc.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    pane.getChildren().add(arc);
                }
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(pane);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял проблему, то вам нужно выбирать дугу окружности в зависимости от взаиморасположения P1P2 и P1P3 (можно определить по знаку векторного произведения).

Проще всего, наверное, менять местами значения `startAngle` и `endAngle` для отрицательных `crossp`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо. Все получилось. Реализовал вот так:

```
if(crossp > 0)
    length = Math.toDegrees(length) - 360;
else
    length = Math.toDegrees(length);
```